# How to assign zero to non exist rows when joining two tables?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables like this:

tableA:

```
CustomerID COUNT(OrderID)
A          3
B          2
C          1
```

tableB:

```
CustomerID COUNT(OrderID)
B          4
D          5
E          6
```

How can I join these 2 tables together, with non-existing rows being 0? Expected result like this:

```
CustomerID COUNT(OrderID) COUNT(OrderID)
A          3              0
B          2              4
C          1              0
D          0              5
E          0              6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `full outer join` such as

```
select
    Coalesce(A.customerId, B.customerId) as CustomerId,
    Coalesce(A.Acount, 0) as Acount,
    Coalesce(B.Bcount, 0) as Bcount
from A full outer join B on A.customerId = B.customerId;
```

Comment: You should be mentioned with Product name which supports this approach.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I'm not sure I follow, unless I'm mistaken(?) a full join is part of [ansi/iso sql join syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Full_outer_join)

Answer (score 0):

You can `union` two queries:

- the first query selects all records from `tableA` and all their matches from `tableB`, allowing the case when there is no match at `tableB`, in which case the second `count` is evaluated to 0, grouped by `CustomerID` of course
- the second query selects all records from `tableB` that have no match in `tableA` (because records having a match were already selected in the first query, this one selects those records from `tableB` that had no match) and gets the `count`, grouping by `CustomerID`, of course

```
SELECT tableA.CustomerID, COUNT(tableA.OrderID), COUNT(tableB.OrderID)
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON tableA.CustomerID = tableB.CustomerID
GROUP BY tableA.CustomerID
UNION
SELECT tableB.CustomerID, 0, COUNT(tableB.OrderID)
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON tableA.CustomerID = tableB.CustomerID
WHERE tableA.CustomerID IS NULL
GROUP BY tableB.CustomerID;
```